# Instance member cannot be used when its already declared

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm declaring UIColors in an extension: UIColor file but I keep getting error like "instance member 'red' cannot be used on type 'UIColor', when I declared it already in the extension file. I will list a picture of the error and the code below.

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZINT.png)

Extension UIColor File

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

  extension UIColor {

var red: CGFloat {
    get {
        let components = self.cgColor.components
        return components![0]
    }
}

var green: CGFloat {
    get {
        let components = self.cgColor.components
        return components![1]
    }
}

var blue: CGFloat {
    get {
        let components = self.cgColor.components
        return components![2]
    }
}

var alpha: CGFloat {
    get {
        return self.cgColor.alpha
    }
}

func alpha(_ alpha: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red: self.red, green: self.green, blue: self.blue, alpha: alpha)
}

func white(_ scale: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(
        red: self.red + (1.0 - self.red) * scale,
        green: self.green + (1.0 - self.green) * scale,
        blue: self.blue + (1.0 - self.blue) * scale,
        alpha: 1.0
    )
}
 }
```

Swift file where I would like to use one of the colors.

```
var color: UIColor = UIColor.red {
    didSet {
        setup()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `red`, `green`, and `blue` property names you added in your extension conflict with the class variables of the same names. Rename the properties in your extension.

FYI - there is no need for your `alpha` method in your extension. `UIColor` already provides the same method (named `withAlphaComponent`).

And your implementation of `red`, `green`, and `blue` may crash. You are assuming the `CGColor` always has 3 components and you assume it is an RGB color. Neither case is always true.

Comment: to make it complete you should mention that his white method is also useless as UIColor has already an initializer specific for that purpose `init(white:alpha:)` https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicolor/1621944-init

Comment: @LeoDabus I thought that at first too but then I looked closer at their `white` method. It's definitely quite different. This one is shifting the current color, not just creating a shade of gray.